# EXT JS 4.2 generate workspace issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm new to ExtJS. I'm running into a problem with tutorial on theming. 
When running `sencha -sdk ~/ext-4.2.0 generate workspace my-workspace` everything is generated fine according to the console log, but according to the tutorial I should get 'ext' and 'packages' folders in my project. Problem is I don't have 'ext' folder. What am I doing wrong here? Did anyone came across similar issue?

Comment: I think it will be create once you generate an app/package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workspace generated by Sencha Cmd is for both Sencha Touch and ExtJs applications. Knowing that it make no sense to include the path to the framework folder. You should first generate a workspace and after that from the workspace folder you generate apps.

Generate workspace

```
sencha generate workspace /path/to/workspace
```

Generate ExtJs app from within the workspace folder

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext generate app ExtApp /path/to/workspace/extApp
```

Generate Sencha Touch app from within the workspace folder

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/touch generate app TouchApp /path/to/workspace/touchApp
```

After that you can build your apps in the same way from the app folder

```
sencha app build
```

More information about generate with Cmd can be found here:
http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/workspaces.html

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this too and came across your post looking for some guidance. I know you've accepted an answer but just wanted to let others know that the ExtJS Theming Guide has the best, most complete (and correct) instructions on setting up a workspace:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/theming.html